# QUERY select SKIPPING with OFFSET issue

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I noticed an issue of `QUERY` formula in Google Spreadsheets.

What I need to use is:

`=query(A:A,"select * offset 1 skipping 2 ",0)`
and
`=query(A:A,"select * skipping 2 ",0)`

which suppose to select separately each odd and even row from an array. When `QUERY` formula without `OFFSET` works great then after adding `OFFSET` before `SKIPPING` I receive `#ERROR`.

I can add `OFFSET` after `SKIPPING` (change places) but then it does not do the right work -- it just drops the first row after skipping.

Note: I need to use `QUERY` because I work directly on an array (after `TRANSPOSE` and `SPLIT`) not on column `A` as stated above for simplifying the problem.

Comment: What is the "Right work". What are you trying to do? Perhaps there is a different approach, but I believe this question is unclear since we aren't told what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, JNevill. I believe I stated it pretty clear but maybe my english is a bit broken, sorry :) What I need to do is to separately select odd and even rows from an array. `A:A` range is only for example. Originally it's an array retrieved from ImportXML but that's not the case. The case is `QUERY` error when using `OFFSET` before `SKIPPING`.

Comment: I guess then "Odd AND even rows" is hard to understand. That means "Every row" as every row is either odd or even. Can you clarify. I'm assuming it means you want to select "Every other row" from your array, but then it's not clear if your OFFSET is meant to enable selecting every ODD row or every EVEN row.

Comment: Odd rows separately and even rows separately (two different formulas in different cells). So the idea was to get each second ("skipping 2") row and each second starting from 2nd ("offset 1 skipping 2") row from the array.

Comment: That makes sense. So the questions is really about that "Even" one only. How to offset the results by 1, then apply `SKIPPING 2`. Makes sense now!

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do by `OFFSET 1 SKIPPING 2` which gives an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest your QUERY function in Google Sheets to achieve this. First offset your range, then apply `Skipping`:

```
=query(query(A:A, "SELECT * OFFSET 1",0),"select * skipping 2 ",0)
```

Comment: Great! That was the idea. I thought maybe it's possible to reach using just one `QUERY` but I see it's not :)

Comment: yea. It's totally an order of operations things. The google applies SKIPPING first, then offsets the result set. SQL is generally not applied in the same order it is written which leads to a lot of confusion for folks first approaching it. Nesting queries is synonymous with subqueries in a RDBMS which we sometimes have to employ to get around order of operations issues like this.

Comment: Honestly, I've never used this QUERY functionality of Google sheets (or google sheets at all really). This is pretty cool functionality. I wish Excel rolled this into their product by default. Sure would solve some nasty `SUMPRODUCTS` and awful array formulas I've come up against.